# Возможно ли сделать авторизацию в приложении через сайт?

Tags: android, kotlin

У меня есть приложение, необходимо сделать авторизацию через почту и пароль сайта, но при этом у меня нет доступа к сайту ( сторонний сайт ), мне просто необходимо чтобы пользователь при вводе данных сайта в приложении мог заходить под своим аккаунтом. Возможно ли такое сделать?

Comment: интересует авторизация или конкретный сайт? если у сайта есть OAuth сервис — можно, иначе — нет

Comment: А каким образом понять, есть ли OAuth сервис на сайте или нет? Спросить у разрабов?

Comment: или у тех поддержки, если сайт мелкий то вряд ли она есть, на гитхабе например есть, с помощью firebase тоже можно реализовать многие популярные

Comment: Через Firebase можно организовать авторизацию в приложении если нет OAuth а так же доступа к данным сайта?

Comment: нет, там популярные способы, гугл, фейсбук, смс, почта и т.п. всего около 15-ти https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth